# 'Bash on Ubuntu on Windows' doesn't work from Jenkins - jenkins job hangs

Tags: jenkins, windows-subsystem-for-linux, repo

We use repo and gerrit tool to manage our git repositories and code reviews.

'repo init' and 'repo sync' work fine on our linux slaves, but we have had major problems on windows slaves:

1. Shebang instruction is ignored on Windows when given in Jenkins 'Execute shell' box, so if we have multiple shells installed on windows slave (MINGW_32, MINGW_64, CYGWIN64, Ubuntu Bash), it is not possible to force the script to be run inside a specific shell by specifying the shebang instcution - it just doesn't work.
2. We managed to run 'repo sync' on the windows slave from jenkins on the MINGW64 shell - which comes with Git for windows installation. However, 'repo sync' is super slow here. We have tried almost all command line switches and 'repo sync' still the bottleneck. It takes almost 10 mins to complete 'repo sync' in an existing workspace when only a few new changes are getting pulled in.
3. We installed 'Bash on Ubuntu on Windows' on a non-jenkins machine and tried 'repo sync' from there and voila!, it complete in a couple of mins.
4. Now, the trouble is that we are unable to use the 'Bash on Ubuntu on Windows' from Jenkins. 
   If we use the Jenkins 'Execute shell' box, we are unable to figure out how to force it to use the Ubuntu bash shell as shebang instruction is ignored on windows slaves (know issue)

If we use Jenkins 'Execute Windows batch command' box, and run something list this:
bash -c ls
This works on the local machine, but if run from jenkins on windows slave the job just hangs and we see the spinning gear progress icon, eventually we have to kill the jenkins job.

May be we need to modify some windows environment variable to force jenkins to use this shell. The bash.exe is located inside C:\Windows\System32 which is already the first entry in the PATH variable, so we are not sure how we end up using the Ubuntu bash shell from Jenkins.

Comment: If you go to Manage Jenkins --> Configure System you will find an option (called "Shell executable") to set the name or absolute path to the shell that you want your shell scripts to use. Is this possible for you?

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't possible - as we have a mixed windows and linux environment, with jenkins master installed on linux, so touching anything in the global config will break the linux builds.

Comment: Hmm, you might be kind of stuck then. You may need to find comparable tools specific on Windows (if available) and use PowerShell, or maybe define the default shell in a custom environment variable and come up with some kind of hack to use it.

Comment: Yes, look like we are stuck. We tried a few things like in a cmd prompt use bash -c 'linux command' AND in a git bash msys windows /c/Windows/System32/bash -c 'linux command' and both work on a local machine, but when we run from jenkins we get the dreaded spinning gear

Answer (score 1):

I believe this happens because the Jenkins agent is not allowed to execute from C:\Windows\System32 on Windows 10 when running in the user context. Oddly enough, the logged-in user does not experience the same restriction from a command prompt.

You can workaround this problem by copying the desired executable (such as bash.exe, curl.exe, etc.) from C:\Windows\System32 to C:\bin and adding that new location to the Path. For Example:

```
set Path=C:\bin\;%Path%
bash -c ls .
```