# Executing wsl.exe with jenkins returns exit -1073740791

Tags: jenkins, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have jenkins set up on a windows 10 computer that has WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux). When I run, for example, from the terminal the simple command ""C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe" --help" it works fine.
Doing the same as a step on jenkins with a windows batch command, I get the exit code-1073740791.

I have tried the following solutions that did not worked out:

-From a tip that it would not be allowed to run on System32, I tried copying the executable to another folder outside System32, but I get the same error;

-From another research, could be running under 32 bit, since the cmd is 64 bit, so I tried calling from the Sysnative "C:\Windows\Sysnative\wsl.exe", but I get file not found;

Also:
Sometime ago I had a similar issue running the bash.exe from the System32, solved it by using another bash.exe (grom gitbash).

Any hints on how to overcome this problem? I really need to run WSL to compile some projects in jenkins jobs.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this is the answer or not (it may be), but the explanation and troubleshooting are a bit long for a comment.

It sounds like you *may* be on the right track with 32-bit vs 64-bit, but possibly a bit confused on which apps are which architecture.

On 64-bit Windows 10, `wsl.exe` is always 64-bit.  You can see this (assuming you have put it back in the right place) via:

```
> file /mnt/c/Windows/System32/wsl.exe
/mnt/c/Windows/System32/wsl.exe: PE32+ executable (console) x86-64, for MS Windows
```

Moving it doesn't change the architecture, of course.

> since the cmd is 64 bit

It's really the architecture of Java and Jenkins that you need to worry about.  Is your Java 32-bit or 64-bit?

```
> file "$(command -v java.exe)"
/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath/java.exe: PE32 executable (console) Intel 80386, for MS Windows
```

I don't run much Java at the moment, but I happened to have a release installed from a while back on one of my systems.  Turns out it is 32-bit.

If your `java.exe` is 32-bit, then this would most likely explain why you can't run `wsl.exe`, which is 64-bit.

> -From another research, could be running under 32 bit, since the cmd is 64 bit, so I tried calling from the Sysnative "C:\Windows\Sysnative\wsl.exe", but I get file not found;

I assume that you are referring to [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1528297/1210833) or something similar.  It *sounds* like you may have tried that from CMD.  Let's do that here for reference:

```
>C:\Windows\Sysnative\wsl.exe

The system cannot find the path specified.

> wsl.exe

Welcome to fish, the friendly interactive shell
Type help for instructions on how to use fish

>
```

This is correct, since both CMD and WSL are 64-bit.  The purpose of Sysnative is to allow you to call a 64-bit from a 32-bit app.

However, if you try that from a 32-bit application, it should work.  Try from "Windows PowerShell (x86)":

```
> wsl.exe

wsl.exe : The term 'wsl.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ wsl.exe
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (wsl.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

> C:\Windows\Sysnative\wsl.exe
Welcome to fish, the friendly interactive shell
Type help for instructions on how to use fish

>
```

If you try that path from within Jenkins (assuming it is 32-bit), what do you get?

If `C:\Windows\Sysnative\wsl.exe` doesn't work for you from Jenkins, and assuming your Java is 32-bit, do you have the option to run 64-bit Java for this task?

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response.

Java is 64 bit and when I run on jenkins "C:\Windows\Sysnative\wsl.exe" it does not find it, so I guess the problem is not here.

Could it be any jenkins configuration that does not allow it to run System32 applications? I read some comments about "You cannot open windows processes through Jenkins running as a service".

Comment: @JoãoP. Bummer - If it's something specific to Jenkins, I won't be able to try it out.  If you happen to find those comments again, can you link them in a reply to me, and I can at least see if I can think of a hack-around?  Thanks!

Comment: Sure, some of those comments were from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16310502/11299409) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57154624/11299409)